# data + methods in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using vuejs3.

There is an error when I'm using from data inside of methods.

Look at my code:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 1,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    check: function () {
      this.count++;
    }
  }
};
```

> Property 'count' does not exist on type '{ check: () => void; }'.

I had a look in all of examples and are like this, What's the issue?

Comment: It seems to work correcly in my code, could you provide a minest reproduction?

Comment: @DengSihan I tried to remove peace by peace of the component until last peace, the file was empty :) then revert it again and everything works fine. Thanks. So weird